# meaning of "Healthy" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

Context : A teacher in the class has been addressing the same thing to the students for over a week. One of the students feel bored and disgusted and he speaks this:

> Isn't it healthy to, like, move on?

What's the meaning of healthy in this context.

According to me, it should be "a good decision". Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The student is copying advice often given to people suffering with emotional trauma or distress.  If you have experienced some loss like a bad divorce or even the death of a relative, it's considered acceptable to be unhappy for some period;  but at some point, you must continue with your life.  In such a situation, a friend might say to you, "It is [psychologically] healthy to move on [with your life]."

Here the student is making a joke that the teacher seems to be obsessing on one topic with the same obsession that they might have with a death in the family or some other traumatic event.

Answer (score 0):

The words ***health*** and ***healthy*** are frequently used with a figuarative or metaphorical meaning.

Sense 3a, of the OED entry on ***healthy*** runs as follows, with examples:

> **Denoting or characteristic of health or sound condition (literal and figurative); opposed to morbid.**
>
> 1600   W. Shakespeare Henry IV, Pt. 2 i. ii. 3   He said..the water it
> self was a good healthy water. View more context for this quotation
>
> 1709   R. Steele Tatler No. 77. ⁋1   With a fresh, sanguine, and
> healthy Look.
>
> 1790   E. Burke Refl. Revol. in France 34   The healthy habit of the
> British constitution. View more context for this quotation
>
> 1878   H. M. Stanley Through Dark Continent II. vii. 199   An
> interchange of small gifts served as a healthy augury for the future.
>
> 1897   Daily News 7 June 9/4   The cutlery trade is in a very healthy
> state.